# Steam games by sneakernet with an external hard drive - Is it possible? if so, how can I do it?

Tags: steam

I've recently moved houses, but unfortunately my new place is in a part of town where the only economical way to get an internet connection is via a prepaid data modem (DSL in my building is super expensive for a super slow speed) and as such large downloads aren't really possible unless I pay about $12 in local currency for every 15 gigs of prepaid data - not really an option.

I have two computers, a laptop and a desktop, both running steam, and my family doens't mind if i leave the laptop around their place to download large files (they live in a different part of town with MUCH faster internet). I was wondering if it's feasible for me to download games onto an external hard drive by bringing my laptop over there, then installing them or transferring them onto my desktop PC over at my new place. I know it's possible to copy steam games over to an external hard drive, but i'm concerned that downloading the game using a different computer than the one that'll actually run it might cause issues. Both computers are running 64-bit Windows 10.